# $\delta-\varepsilon$ definition of $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

I know that

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=L \mbox{ means } \forall \varepsilon>0 \:\exists N\:\forall x\:(x>N\rightarrow|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon)$$

$$\lim_{x \to a} f(x)=\infty \mbox{ means } \forall N \:\exists \delta>0\:\forall x(0<|x-a|<\delta|\rightarrow f(x)>N)$$

I've combined these the following way but not sure if it's precise:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=\infty \mbox{ means } \forall M \:\exists N\:\forall x\:(x>N\rightarrow f(x)>M)$$

Is it correct definition of this limit?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Importantly, the range tolerance is given and then the domain tolerance can be chosen as a function of the range tolerance.

Comment: It's the $\delta$-$\varepsilon$ limit with neither $\delta$ nor $\varepsilon$ :) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definition:

For all $\epsilon \in \mathbb R_+$ exists $k$, such that for all $x$

$$|f(x)|>\epsilon,\space \space \text{when}  \space x>k.$$

So yes it appears correct.